# getting complete data after submit button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a web form where there is one control list box and a data grid view to display data.
Everything works fine when I open the app for the first time, the list box is also perfectly loaded and all the data is displayed in the data grid view.

But when I click the submit button, the listbox data is lost and also the latest data I have entered in the app is not showing in the grid view.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(!IsPostBack)
                {
                    new M_DropDown().Get_Ward(lstTole);
                    GridCustomer.DataSource = new M_GetUser().GetCustomer();
                    GridCustomer.DataBind();
                }
                DataTable dt = new M_GetUser().GetCustomer();
                GridCustomer.DataSource = dt;
                GridCustomer.DataBind();

            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
        }
```

On submit button click, I have cleared all the controls.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // other code blocks ommitted
         case "1":
                        lblMessage.Text = "customer added successfully!!!";
                        div_message.Visible = true;
                        div_message.Attributes.Add("class", "callout callout-info");
                        txtHouseNumber.Value = string.Empty;
                        txtName.Value = string.Empty;
                        txtCustId.Value = string.Empty;
                        txtCustContact.Value = string.Empty;
                        lstTole.Items.Clear();
                        break;
        }
```

Why is it so? Why I am not getting the listbox data and last inserted data on successful button submit event?

Comment: could you share some of your markup?

Comment: My form is very lengthy... it contains textboxes, list box and submit button then a grid view to show the inserted data.